# how to properly shutdown JVM with akka remote actor

Tags: java, akka

I'm trying to shutdown a very simple akka 1.2 remote actors with the Java API like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Actors.remote().start("localhost", 2552);
    Actors.registry().shutdownAll();
}
```

But the JVM isn't terminated because of some threads still hang out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is simple: you did not stop the remote module.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Actors.remote().start("localhost", 2552);
  Actors.registry().shutdownAll();
  Actors.remote().shutdown();
}
```

This will properly stop everything.